# what i need on my server to support java webprojects?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, hosting, application-server

I'm beginner in java and i want to have a VPS
what i need to install on my server to support java projects
i think only
JVM 6.0
JBOSS
MYSQL
are Enough
any one can help me about the softwares and the version i must install on my linux server, and how can i install them?

Answer (score 1):

> ... and how can i install them?

As with all first-rate open source software products, you:

1. go to the website; e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html, http://mysql.com/ and http://jboss.org/,
2. download the relevant version of the software for your platform,
3. read the installation document that is (typically) linked on or near the download page, and
4. follow the instructions.

If you have problems with finding or installing software, a more appropriate place to ask is on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

The three you mention are enough for Java web apps.  I believe JBOSS uses Tomcat for its servlet/JSP engine, so you're all set there.

You'll need the MySQL Connector-J JDBC driver.

You'll also want to have JSTL (JSP Standard Tag Library) in your Tomcat /lib or server/lib directory.  You should not write JSPs without it.

That is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

JVM, JBoss, and MySQL should be enough. In fact, it is more than enough ;-)

If you want to use Enterprise JavaBeans, then JBoss, or a similar JavaEE Application server is necessary. However if you want to develop Java Web applications that do not need EJB, you can install a lighter weight Java server, commonly known as a Servlet Container. A popular and easy to use Servlet Container is Apache Tomcat.

Comment: every one says that Apache tomcat have some problems like shutting down, bad servlet generation and ...
any way , can i handle tomcat AS and do you have experience in tomcat

Comment: Haven't encountered any of those problems. I have used Tomcat in production for many clients and overall it is a reliable server. Tcat server is an enterprise-grade Java Servlet container based on Tomcat. You can use that instead: http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat-server-enterprise-tomcat-application-server?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=LINK_TcatServer&utm_campaign=G_Brands_AU_Search